# assigning [sender.tag] to a variable in Swift

Tags: swift, button, tags

I want to assign the value of a Button tag(sender.tag) to a variable in Swift, but I get an error message stating it cannot assign an Element, whatever that is. I understood that this was an Integer value and have seen past examples with Objective C that have done this.How can this be achieved in Swift please.

Comment: It seems it was treating it as an array, as I was putting square brackets around sender.tag. Works fine now without them and produces an integer as expected.

Comment: Please close this as it's a simple typographical error, visible in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same trick:

```
var tag:NSInteger = yourSender.tag;
```